# VMWARE View install

Tags: vmware

VMWARe.com  at https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/details?downloadGroup=VIEWCLIENTS_LINUX32_170&productId=331&rPId=3638#product_downloads

states:

"To download the VMware Horizon View client from the Ubuntu Software Center, configure Ubuntu Software Center to allow software packaged by Canonical for their partners. Next, open a web browser in Ubuntu and click on the Download link."

How does one accomplish that? (Step-by-step)

When I use Ubuntu Software center, the version from VMWARE isnot found and the version there is too old for use at my institution.

Answer (score 2):

1st Download it VMware View Client

2nd check canonical partners is enabled or not

Open Software Center > Edit > Software Source ( check the given below pic )

[image]

If not open terminal and copy paste the following commands

```
 sudo apt-add-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
 sudo apt-get update
```

Double click the file which you have downloaded earlier and it will open in " Ubuntu Software Center " then click " Install "

Done